# Cannot delete orphaned domain with ntdsutil

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, dcpromo

I have a problem deleting an orphaned subdomain from a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD. The situation is as follows:

1. dcpromo failed in demoting the only DC of the subdomain. The DC was therefore demoted forcefully.
2. No DC for the subdomain is in the AD at the moment (as shown in GUI).
3. If I use ntdsutil and connect to the sub domain, it says that there is no site, no server and no naming context for the domain.
4. The subdomain shows in AD domains and trusts, but I cannot do anything, because it cannot find a DC for the subdomain.

If I call "remove selected domain" for the subdomain, the tool asks for confirmations but then fails with error 0x2162, i. e. it tells me that there are still DCs left for the subdomain. However, I cannot delete any DCs or naming contexts using `ntdsutil`, because it does not show any.

Any suggestions on removing the domain are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at http://www.winserverkb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/windows-2000-active-directory/10198/DsRemoveDsDomainW-error-0x2162. There was an old entry in CN=LostAndFoundConfig,CN=Configuration,... containing references to the subdomain. After removing this, I could remove the subdomain from AD domains and trusts.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is not the best approach but look for the orphaned DC in AD Sites and Services. If you find it there then delete it's NTDS Settings component, then delete the server, then delete the Site and Subnet for the orphaned domain (if the site and subnet is not valid for the remaining parent domain), then delete the domain from AD Domains and Trusts. You'll wind up with some DNS cleanup to do more than likely and may need to do some cleanup with ADSIEdit as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, the server of the subdomain is not in AD Sites and Services. I can only find the two DCs of our primary domain.

Comment: Btw, i cannot find the subdomain in the DNS settings any more, it is just in the AD domains and trusts.